# Sound capture. MacOS permissions. Java Audio API

Tags: java, macos, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I'm trying to capture sound from microphone via Java Sound API.
I'm using sample code from [github](https://gist.github.com/teocci/39437102a5c3a620f1ba2b75091d8429) and it works perfect on Windows system, but when it runs on MacOS - audio-line buffer returns zero-bytes.

Also if I compile project to jar and run it via administrator permission - appears a message to give access to microphone and after I grant it - all works.

So the question is how to make permission request from code and run app without sudo?

Thanks!

Comment: Just compiled this with `javac AudioCapture01.java` and run with `java AudioCapture01` without issue. `java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)` on macOS High Sierra. It might be worth checking everything is up to date. and making sure nothing extra has been added to the example code first.

Comment: I have macOS Mojave - working only with root

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you have to use the default terminal that comes with mac to execute jar file. That will worked.

The third party terminal, such as iTerm,  it's not ok.

Comment: Yup, I`m using default terminal

Comment: Thanks for commenting this. It was driven me crazy.